# Regex for all character in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a web page that generates QR code.
I want the link to look like "website.name/qr/data_to_convert"

So I used the following in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule    ^([\s\S]+)/?$    create.php?data=$1
```

This is so that I can convert any character set to QR code.

But I get an error.

So I tried to make it:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\-\+\=\{\}\[\]\;\:\'\"\<\,\>\.\?\|\~\`\s\/\\]+)/?$    create.php?data=$1
```

And now the data that is passed is "*create.php*"

I have just one rewrite rule in this htaccess file apart from the

```
RewriteEngine On
```

command.

What should the regexr be so that I can include any text after "qr/" to convert it to QR code.

Thanks.

Update: I get the data passed as *create.php* even for the first regex

Comment: you want *create.php?data=$1* to look like *website.name/qr/data_to_convert* ? I'm having trouble understanding what is your requirement.

Comment: @Veverke Yes. Exactly. But I want the data_to_convert to be any character. like a link `http://atulbhats.com` or a data like `<p>hello</p>`

Comment: What would the output for `<p>hello</p>` look like ?

Comment: It should look like this : http://atulbhats.com/qr/temp/test842bb7e4c7972f2dd0bdf620c16aee6d.png 

But given the Regex in htaccess as mentioned above, I am getting the QR code that decodes to http://create.php

So what Regex do I use such that any number of characters entered after _qr/_ will be taken as input?